# do tableView.reloadData() in external class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, reloaddata

I am doing a Parse query from an external class. This query give me back the array for populate the tableview, so in the viewDidLoad method I call MyClass.load(array) and the async parse method `findObjectInBackground` return me the array filled but in the time that the findObject retrive me the objects the tableView is already created and I see an empty tableView, I did a fast google search for the problem and I found that I have to use the `self.tableView.reloadData()` method, I tried it but I am in an external class and the delegate for the tableView is in the tableViewController, there is any way to refresh  the tableView from an external Class?
If you need some code example just ask it, thank you!

*EDIT* **I'm using Swift 2.0**

Comment: How about setting up a custom delegate between your external class and ViewController?

Comment: How does `findObjectInBackground` return the array for you ? In a completion handler ?

Comment: @Bobj-C yes, it returns an array of [PFObject]

Comment: @LucaAlberto so in the completion handler can't you do `self.tableData = [parsePFObjectsArray]` then `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set custom delegate between your external class and ViewControllers.

check for creating [custom delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020539/how-to-make-custom-delegate-in-ios-app)

Also, you can use NSNotificationCenter for send and post notifications. please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676398/how-to-post-and-receive-an-notification)

Comment: Hi, can you make me an example in Swift! @darshan