# How do I perform the tableView method reloadData() in an external class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to do a `self.tableView.reloadData()` in an external class, not in the tableViewController. I found that I have to do a custom delegate in my class but I can't figure out how to do that! Someone can show me with some code example in Swift how to do it, thanks!

Comment: to reload data of a table view you dont need to do it in a delegate. you can do it from everywhere where you can access the table view. so if you pass the tableview to an object, it can reload that, no matter if it is implementing the delegate or not. though I'd always advice to have the dlegate/datasource implementation not in the view controller. Over all your question is quite vague. I vote for closure.

Comment: @vikingosegundo No, I can't pass the tableView in my object and do the tableView.reloadData, it doesn't work for me!

Comment: and why doenst it work? be more specific and post code that isnt working for you.

Comment: please don't repost question, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262964/do-tableview-reloaddata-in-external-class

Comment: @vikingosegundo this is more specific? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262964/do-tableview-reloaddata-in-external-class

Comment: No, but you posted the same question twice. dont do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your protocol or just make easier way to do with `NSNotification` like that;

```
class xViewController: UIViewController {

    let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height), style: .Plain)

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadMyTableView:", name: "updateNotification", object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "updateNotification", object: nil)
    }

    func reloadMyTableView(notification: NSNotification) {
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And post your notification from where do you want to reload;

```
class yViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateNotification", object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a PFQuery from Parse to fill the array that will populate my tableView. I'm doing this with findObjectInbackground like that: `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded...` I put the NSNotification into the query to do the reloadData but it doesn't work!